# How to add the class properties plugin to webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm trying to get the [`@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties) to work with webpack.

I have installed the plugin with node package manager (`npm`).

I don't have a `.babelrc`, so I'm assuming that this plugin is supposed to go into `webpack.config.js`.

I found [this page](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/plugins/) which led me to believe that the following was a good setup for including the plugin in the `webpack.config.js` file:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ClassPropertiesPlugin = require("@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"); //installed via npm
const config = {
    entry:  __dirname + '/js/index.jsx',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
                loader: "file-loader?name=/public/[name].[ext]",
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['css-loader'],
            },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [ClassPropertiesPlugin]
};


module.exports = config;
```

However, this caused the error

```
<personal info>\static\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js:348
                        throw err;
                        ^

TypeError: arguments[i].apply is not a function
    at Compiler.apply (<personal info><personal info>\static\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:375:16)
    at webpack (<personal info>\static\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js:33:19)
    at processOptions (<personal info>\static\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js:335:15)
    at yargs.parse (<personal info>\static\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js:397:2)
    at Object.Yargs.self.parse (<personal info>\static\node_modules\yargs\yargs.js:533:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (<personal info>\static\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js:152:7)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
```

When I [looked into it](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2217), it seemed that this meant I was including the plugin incorrectly, but I'm not sure how. I've also tried the following with the exact same error:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const config = {
    entry:  __dirname + '/js/index.jsx',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
                loader: "file-loader?name=/public/[name].[ext]",
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['css-loader'],
            },
        ]
    },
    plugins: ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
};


module.exports = config;
```

I also can't do `new ClassPropertiesPlugin()` because it says it's not a constructor.

Without this plugin, my webpack (which fails to build a particular `.jsx` file 
 which is why I need this plugin, but otherwise works fine) looks like

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const config = {
    entry:  __dirname + '/js/index.jsx',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
                loader: "file-loader?name=/public/[name].[ext]",
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['css-loader'],
            },
        ]
    },
};


module.exports = config;
```

I would like the `npm run build` to work without throwing an error, and have the plugin compile the javascript correctly. By correctly, I mean that the compiler does not throw [this error](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/554) on a particular file I'm using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you would have a [.babelrc](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/react-bb-kit/blob/master/.babelrc#L31) file at the root of your project (just create one if it doesn’t exist) and include it under `"plugins"`, otherwise you can include a babel config in your package.json (not recommended) or in your webpack config’s babel-loader [options](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/babel-loader/#options).

Comment: I ended up needing to install a lot more using `npm` and change some things in my `package.json` file for this to finally work (not output any compile errors). But, in the end, this worked. Thank you.

Comment: What did you all install?

Comment: @Marc You can view my React Bare Bones Kit: https://github.com/mattcarlotta/react-bb-kit which includes how manually set up: Webpack, babel, SCSS, stylelint, eslint... etc. and what packages are required.