# SyntaxError: Missing class properties transform

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I have problem with babel transform. After add handle event in my React container i got this error.

SyntaxError: Missing class properties transform.

```
  21 |     // handlers
  22 |
> 23 |     onIncrement = () => {
     |     ^
  24 |         const { dispatch } = this.props;
  25 |
  26 |         dispatch(valueDecrement())
```

My .babelrc

```
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "@babel/env",
            {
                "targets": {
                    "browsers": [
                      "last 2 versions"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],

        "@babel/react",
        "@babel/typescript",
    ],
}
```

My webpack loader

```
...
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
            },
        ],
    },
...
```

Comment: I guess you need to install the plugin? [link](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/7.3.0/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties)

Comment: Same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55661413/how-to-add-the-class-properties-plugin-to-webpack/55667018#55667018

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solve. Need to install @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties and add this plugin to the .babelrc.
[Link](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties)

Comment: 1. npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties
      2. webpack.config.js -> module -> rules -> loader -> options -> plugins: ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]